Error: FCM Migrating to HTTP v1 API from Legacy API
I am trying to migrate FCM from legacy API to HTTP V1 API. A sample "working code before" and after the modification is as follows:
Before:
const payload = 
            {
                data:
                {
                    title: "Alert: New Query",
                    body: "You have received a new order query",
                    icon: "default"
                }
            }
    
            const options = {
                priority: "high"
            }
            await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(pharmToken, payload, options)

After:
 const message ={
                name: 'Alert',
                notification: {
                    title: 'Alert: New Query!'
                },
                data:
                {
                    title: "Alert: New Query",
                    body: "You have received a new order query",
                    icon: "default"
                },
                android: {
                    notification: {
                        title: "Alert: New Query",
                        body: "You have received a new order query",
                        icon: "default"
                    },
                    priority: "high",
                },
                token:pharmToken,

            }
    
            await admin.messaging().send(message)

But Typescript is throwing an error at "message" within await admin.messaging().send(message)
It says:
Argument of type '{ name: string; notification: { title: string; }; data: { title: string; body: string; icon: string; }; android: { notification: { title: string; body: string; icon: string; sound: string; }; priority: string; }; token: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Message'.
Type '{ name: string; notification: { title: string; }; data: { title: string; body: string; icon: string; }; android: { notification: { title: string; body: string; icon: string; sound: string; }; priority: string; }; token: any; }' is not assignable to type 'TokenMessage'.
The types of 'android.priority' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"high" | "normal" | undefined'
I am using admin-sdk

I found the issue from this link
The IDE is not happy with the priority set in the given manner. Instead the following works:
const androidConfig: admin.messaging.AndroidConfig = {
                priority: 'high', 
                notification: {
                    title: "Alert: New Query",
                    body: "You have received a new order query",
                    icon: "default"
                },
            };
            const message ={
                name: 'Alert',
                notification: {
                    title: 'Alert: New Query!'
                },
                data:
                {
                    title: "Alert: New Query",
                    body: "You have received a new order query",
                    icon: "default"
                },
                android: androidConfig,
                token:pharmToken,

            }
    
            await admin.messaging().send(message)


Here's the interface for Message . Its doesn't have any name type
export interface BaseMessage {
    data?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    notification?: Notification;
    android?: AndroidConfig;
    webpush?: WebpushConfig;
    apns?: ApnsConfig;
    fcmOptions?: FcmOptions;
}

export interface TokenMessage extends BaseMessage {
    token: string;
}

Try priority with single qoute
collapseKey?: string;
/**
* Priority of the message. Must be either `normal` or `high`.
*/
priority?: ('high' | 'normal');

